# Ruby - Airbourne Rspec API testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to write an api test but I can't figure out how to do it. 
I converted curl to ruby and got a block like below

```js
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("https://example.com/api/v2/tests.json")
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
request.basic_auth("test@gmail.com", "Abcd1234")

req_options = {
  use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end
```

I wrote the test as below

```js
describe 'Test to GET' do
  it 'should return 200' do
  
  expect_json_types(name: :string)
  expect_json(name: 'test')
    expect_status(200)
  end
end
```

My question how do i use the api call to test this. Should i add it in a separate file or in the same file above describe. I haven't worked with Ruby before and couldn't find anything online as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [airborne](https://github.com/brooklynDev/airborne) which uses [rest_client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) to make API calls.
In order to use airborne's matchers (`expect_json`, etc), you need to make your API call inside the test. This means you your test should look like:

```rb
describe 'Test to GET' do
  it 'should return 200' do
    authorization_token = Base64.encode64('test@gmail.com:Abcd1234')
    get(
      "https://example.com/api/v2/tests.json",
      { 'Authorization' => "Basic #{authorization_token}" }
    )
    expect_json_types(name: :string)
    expect_json(name: 'test')
    expect_status(200)
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried using get inside the test but I am not sure how to use the authentication. I should use the username and password with the call. Curl looks like this "curl https://example.com/api/v2/tests.json \
  -v -u test@gmail.com:Abcd1234"

Comment: @Jane I've updated my answer to include basic auth.

Comment: I tried to use the same format for post and delete and delete doesn't seem to work. I am getting 401 unauthorised error. any pointers? Post works fine.

Comment: Hmm the delete and post methods should work the same. Could it be a problem on the API side?

Comment: i tried it with Faraday and delete works with Faraday. But with Faraday, I seem to have trouble with using Airborne expect_status or any other assertions which seem to work with the code you suggested with rest_client